# Why the "tidyverse" package cannot be installed in R?

Tags: installation, tidyverse

[The Warnings are shown as the picture in this link. And my R version is most updated 4.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQJ6l.png)

Comment: please post the Warnings as text NOT as screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message, it shows that you do not have `rtools` installed. You can follow the link and follow the instructions to install `rtools`.

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html

Then, you can restart R and try again with `tidyverse`.

If you still have issues with `tidyverse` from CRAN, then you can try installing the package from [GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse).

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyverse")
```